# why does toggle() work with document but not body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was fiddling around with some jQuery when I saw that the toggle() only toggled when fired from the document than from the body.

For example

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('div').toggle();
});
//this toggles

$('body').click(function(){
    $('div').toggle();
});
//this doesn't toggle
```

**Why won't it toggle with** `body`?

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wNXLY/673/)

Comment: Note that the body doesn't necessarily fill the whole document. See: http://imgur.com/io4mvKi This means there's nothing to click to bring the box back.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when your `div` is not there, the `height` of `body` is `0`, So you can't click that when div is not there.

Just give some `height` & `width` to your `body`.

```
body{
    height:1000px;
    width:1000px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wNXLY/674/)

Comment: hmm that sounds reasonable. But when the `div` is not there, why does the `body` retain its styles? see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wNXLY/676/